# Django Rest Framework nested serializer creation

Tags: javascript, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I have troubles saving object with foreign key.
I have two Django model like (going to simplfy them, for this purpose, but the point remains):

```
class Model1(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class Model2(models.Model):
    label = models.CharField()
    rel = models.ForeignKey("Model1",  related_name="model2s")
```

and two Serializers like:

```
class model1SER(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
         model = Model1
         fields = ['pk', 'name']
         

class model2SER(serializers.ModelSerializer):
     rel = model1SER()
     class Meta:
          model = Model2
          fields = "all"

      def create(self, validated_data):
           model2 = Model2.objects.create(**validated_data)
           return model2
```

I post using axios POST to a modelViewSet, and the POST JSON body looks like:
`{'label': "xxxx", 'rel': {'pk': 1, 'name': "foo"}}`

Trying to create an object, returns either 1) "**rel_id violates not null...**" or **Cannot assign "OrderedDict([('name': 'foo')])": "Model2.rel" must be a "Model1" instance**.

And after inspecting, the validated data only contains:
`('rel', OrderedDict([('name', 'foo')]))` without **pk**.

I have also tried replacing pk with id, adding id and many more, but can not get to save a object using nested serializer.

The Model1 Serializer is used to get the data for all Model1 objects.
After selecting a single one, it is appended to a post data for a Model2 Serializer, so the structure of serialized data remains the same.

Can I change the create method to somehow get the validated_data['rel']['pk'] ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Nested Writable](https://github.com/beda-software/drf-writable-nested) library for nested creation, as documented in the Django Rest Framework serializers.

Answer (score 0):

You can separate reading and writing serializer for Model2.
reading can be used for get method and writing can be used for post method.

for get method :

```
class model2ReadSER(serializers.ModelSerializer):
     rel = model1SER()
     class Meta:
          model = Model2
          fields = "all"
```

for post method:

```
class model2WriteSER(serializers.ModelSerializer):
     class Meta:
          model = Model2
          fields = "all"
```

and put only id of Model1 object in your post data:

```
{'label': "xxxx", 'rel': 1}
```